# Preventing pagebreak within (sub)section

Tags: page-breaking

Is there a way to completely prevent latex to automatically put pagebreaks within (sub)sections? I've only found ways to prevent breaks before or after sections.

If there is a way I would like to still be able to manually force pagebreaks - is this possible?

Comment: what do you mean by `prevent latex to automatically put pagebreaks`? Do you mean you do not want the section to span more than one page? No matter how long it is? btw, a MWE is also best to answer such questions.

Comment: If you wrap the desired scope in a group -- be sure to end with a blank line or `\par` within the group -- you can set `\interlinepenalty=10000`.  That's entirely manual, of course, so not really convenient.  (Also not tested at the moment, for lack of a good test file.)